# How can I prevent or trap StopIteration exception in the yield-calling function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, exception, generator

A generator-returning function (i.e. one with a `yield` statement in it) in one of our libraries fails some tests due to an unhandled `StopIteration` exception.  For convenience, in this post I'll refer to this function as `buggy`.

I have not been able to find a way for `buggy` to prevent the exception (without affecting the function's normal operation).  Similarly, I have not found a way to trap the exception (with a `try`/`except`) within `buggy`.

(*Client code* using `buggy` can trap this exception, but this happens too late, because the code that has the information necessary to properly handle the condition leading to this exception is the `buggy` function.)

The actual code and test case I am working with are far too complicated to post here, so I have created a very simple, but also *extremely artificial* toy example that illustrates the problem.

First, the module with the `buggy` function:

```
# mymod.py

import csv  # essential!

def buggy(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile) as stream:

        reader = csv.reader(stream)

        # how to test *here* if either stream is at its end?

        for row in reader:
            yield row
```

As indicated by the comment, the use of the `csv` module (from the Python 3.x standard library) is an essential feature of this problem<sup>1</sup>.

The next file for the example is a script that is meant to *stand in for "client code"*.  In other word, this script's "real purpose" beyond this example is largely irrelevant.  Its role in the example is to provide a simple, reliable way to elicit the problem with the `buggy` function.  (Some of its code could be repurposed for a test case in a test suite, for example.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# myscript.py

import sys
import mymod

def print_row(row):
    print(*row, sep='\t')

def main(csvfile, mode=None):
    if mode == 'first':
        print_row(next(mymod.buggy(csvfile)))
    else:
        for row in mymod.buggy(csvfile):
            print_row(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

The script takes the path to a CSV file as a mandatory argument, and an optional second argument.  If the second argument is ommitted, or it is anything other than the string `"first"`, the script will print to `stdout` the information in the CSV file, but in *TSV* format.  If the second argument is the string `"first"`, only the information in the first row will be so printed.

The `StopIteration` exception I am trying to trap arises when `myscript.py` script is invoked with an empty file and the string `"first"` as arguments<sup>2</sup>.

Here is an example of this code in action:

```
% cat ok_input.csv
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
% ./myscript.py ok_input.csv
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
% ./myscript.py ok_input.csv first
1   2   3
% cat empty_input.csv
# no output (of course)
% ./myscript.py empty_input.csv
# no output (as desired)
% ./myscript.py empty_input.csv first
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myscript.py", line 19, in <module>
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
  File "./myscript.py", line 13, in main
    print_row(next(mymod.buggy(csvfile)))
StopIteration
```

**Q:** How can I prevent or trap this `StopIteration` exception in the lexical scope of the `buggy` function?

---

**IMPORTANT:** Please keep in mind that, in the example given above, the `myscript.py` script is stand-in for "client code", and is therefore outside of our control.  This means that any approach that would require changing the `myscript.py` script would not solve the actual real-world problem, and therefore it would not be an acceptable answer to this question.

One important difference between the simple example shown above and our actual situation is that in our case, the problematic input stream does not come from an empty file.  The problem arises in cases where `buggy` (or, rather, its real-world counterpart) reaches the end of this stream "too early", so to speak.

I think it may be enough if I could test whether either `stream` is at its end, before the `for row in reader:` line, but I have not figured a way to do this either.  Testing whether the value returned by `stream.read(1)` is 0 or 1 will tell me if stream is at its end, but in the latter case `stream`'s internal pointer will be left pointing one byte too far into `csvfile`'s content.  (Neither `stream.seek(-1, 1)` nor `stream.tell()` work at this point.)

---

Lastly, to anyone who would like post an answer to this question: it would be most efficient if you were to take advantage of the example code I have provided above to test your proposal before posting it.

---

**EDIT:** One variation of `mymod.py` that I tried was this:

```
import csv  # essential!

def buggy(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile) as stream:

        reader = csv.reader(stream)

        try:
            firstrow = next(reader)
        except StopIteration:
            firstrow = None

        if firstrow != None:
            yield firstrow

        for row in reader:
            yield row
```

This variation fails with pretty much the same error message as does the original version.

When I first read @mcernak's proposal, I thought that it was pretty similar to the variation above, and therefore expected it to fail too.  Then I was pleasantly surprised to discover that this is not the case!  Therefore, as of now, there is one definite candidate to get bounty.  That said, *I would love to understand why the variation above fails to trap the exception, while @mcernak's succeeds.*

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The actual case I'm dealing with is legacy code; switching from the `csv` module to some alternative is not an option for us in the short term.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> Please, disregard entirely the question of what this demonstration script's "right response should be" when it gets invoked with an empty file and the string `"first"` as arguments.  The particular combination of inputs that elicits the `StopIteration` exception in this post's demonstration does not represent the real-world condition that causes our code to emit the problematic `StopIteration` exception.  Therefore, the "correct response", whatever that may be, of the demonstration script to the empty file plus `"first"` string combination would be irrelevant to the real-world problem I am dealing with.</sup>

Comment: I don't know how your real code looks like, but this toy example only illustrates that your `main` function is buggy. The `buggy` function is perfectly fine.

Comment: If you want `buggy` to do some *other* perfectly fine thing, different from the one it's doing now, then say what and maybe we can help with that (or tell you it's impossible).

Comment: You're still ignoring the question how you want `buggy` to behave. The client code asks for something that's simply not there. What is `buggy` supposed to do?

Comment: The variation in your EDIT makes no sense. You act like the StopIteration the client got came from the csv reader, rather than being a signal from `buggy` itself, informing the client that there's no more. It's *the client* that violates this fundamental contract of iteration in Python (by not handling this signal), not `buggy`.

Comment: This definitely seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Trying to trap StopIteration deosn't seem like the right approach to what you original were trying to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trap the `StopIteration` exception in the lexical scope of the `buggy` function this way:

```
import csv  # essential!

def buggy(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile) as stream:

        reader = csv.reader(stream)

        try:
            yield next(reader)
        except StopIteration:
            yield 'dummy value'

        for row in reader:
            yield row
```

You basically manually request the first value from the `reader` iterator and

- if this succeeds, the first line is read from the csv file and is yielded to the caller of `buggy` function
- if this fails, as is the case for empty csv files, some string e.g. `dummy value` is yielded to prevent the caller of the `buggy` function from crashing

Afterwards, if the csv file was not empty, the remaining rows will be read (and yielded) in the for cycle.

---

**EDIT:** to illustrate why the other variation of `mymod.py` mentioned in the question does not work, I've added some print statements to it:

```
import csv  # essential!

def buggy(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile) as stream:

        reader = csv.reader(stream)

        try:
            print('reading first row')
            firstrow = next(reader)
        except StopIteration:
            print('no first row exists')
            firstrow = None

        if firstrow != None:
            print('yielding first row: ' + firstrow)
            yield firstrow

        for row in reader:
            print('yielding next row: ' + row)
            yield row

        print('exiting function open')
```

Running it gives the following output:

```
% ./myscript.py empty_input.csv first
reading first row
no first row exists
exiting function open
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 15, in <module>
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
  File "myscript.py", line 9, in main
    print_row(next(mymod.buggy(csvfile)))
```

That shows, that in case that the input file is empty, the first `try..except` block correctly handles the `StopIteration` exception and that the `buggy` function continues on normally.
The exception that the caller of the `buggy` gets in this case is due to the fact that the `buggy` function does not yield any value before completing.

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  As of now, your answer is the clear candidate for getting the bounty.  I find the fact that your proposal works extremely puzzling, though, for reasons I spell out in an **EDIT** I just added to my post.

Comment: @kjo I've included an explanation of why the code variation that you've added to the post does not work to my answer

Comment: This of course *always* yields the dummy value if there are no rows, not just in case of the client's `if mode == 'first':` branch but also in its `else:` branch where it might be undesirable. Or maybe they want it there, too. Who knows... well the OP probably does, but refuses to tell...

Comment: Just a suggestion for the EDIT part: add an explicit `return 'everything went fine in buggy'` at the end of `buggy` and include the `StopIteration` line in the output.

Comment: Ah, the last line of your edit is the clincher!  That's what I was missing.  This explains why everything I tried to trap the exception failed.  Now I finally get it.  Thank you!

Comment: The first sentence is wrong, you're not trapping "the" StopIteration exception (that the client is getting and that the question is talking about). You're trapping a different one.

Answer (score 1):

**mcernak** solves and describes the problem you have well

However, there is a design problem underlying the issue: the caller *sometimes* isn't expecting a generator, but a non-empty iterator

Looking at this from another aspect, what should happen if the file is missing? Does it make more sense for the function handle `IOError` from `open` and return some sentinel or raise it to the caller?

Instead of trying to coerce your generator to work with callers mistreating it, consider

- providing two functions (one could call the other)
- providing an argument for a maximal count of rows from the generator (probably best)

```py
# mymod.py

import csv
import itertools
def notbuggy(csvfile, max_rows=None):
    with open(csvfile) as stream:
        yield from itertools.islice(csv.reader(stream), max_rows)
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# myscript.py

import sys
import mymod

def print_row(row):
    print(*row, sep='\t')

def main(csvfile, mode=None):
    max_rows = 1 if mode == "first" else None
    for row in mymod.notbuggy(csvfile, max_rows):
        print_row(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

---

When using `next()`, the calling logic must agree to one of

- never call it on an empty iterable (check file first?)
- handle an Exception from the generator (`StopIteration`, some custom `Exception`)
- handle some empty sentinel (perhaps `""`, some string, `None`, or `object`..)

However, the caller does none of these, so the guarantees are not well set!

What if the caller wanted more than a single row or interprets the empty sentinel as a value? Unless these are somehow communicated in documentation, the caller can always misuse a function and not know why it has unexpected behavior.

```py
>>> next(iter(()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> g = iter((1,))
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> print_row("STOP SENTINEL")
S   T   O   P       S   E   N   T   I   N   E   L
```